# Has anyone heard of SCHEMA page layout tool?

Tags: history, file-format, text, identify-this-software, besm-6

I've found a text formatting tool, under the name of **SCHEMA**, which would accept an input language like

```
*RED
*0STA*NN*RG*1RL*0MCS1 20
*3/
*MDLorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
*MDconsectetur adipiscing elit,
*MDsed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
*MDut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
*MD
*MD
*P
*E
*END
```

and produced line printer output like

```
.----------------------------------------------------------------------------------.
I                                                                                  I
I                                                                                  I
I                                                                                  I
I                                                                                  I
I                                                                                  I
I                                                                                  I
I                                                                                  I
I                                                                                  I
I                                                                                  I
I           LОRЕМ IРSUМ DОLОR                                                      I
I                                                                                  I
I               SIТ АМЕТ,                                                          I
I                                                                                  I
I              СОNSЕСТЕТUR                                                         I
I                                                                                  I
I            АDIРISСING ЕLIТ,                                                      I
I                                                                                  I
I             SЕD DО ЕIUSМОD                                                       I
I                                                                                  I
I           ТЕМРОR INСIDIDUNТ                                                      I
I                                                                                  I
I          UТ LАВОRЕ ЕТ DОLОRЕ                                                     I
I                                                                                  I
I             МАGNА АLIQUА.                                                        I
I                                                                                  I
...
I                                                                                  I
I                                                                                  I
.----------------------------------------------------------------------------------.
```

so that each page would fit exactly on one sheet of fan-fold line printer paper vertically, and occupy half the sheet horizontally.

Experimentation shows that the number 20 appears to be the width of the centered field, and the number before RL appears to specify line separation. For example, if `20` is replaced with `30`, and `1RL` with `0RL`, I get

```
...
I           LОRЕМ IРSUМ DОLОR SIТ АМЕТ,                                            I
I           СОNSЕСТЕТUR АDIРISСING ЕLIТ,                                           I
I              SЕD DО ЕIUSМОD ТЕМРОR                                               I
I                    INСIDIDUNТ                                                    I
I            UТ LАВОRЕ ЕТ DОLОRЕ МАGNА                                             I
I                     АLIQUА.                                                      I
...
```

This language does not look like an original Soviet invention, and it does not look like DEC [RUNOFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TYPSET_and_RUNOFF) nor like IBM [SCRIPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCRIPT_(markup)).

Does it ring a bell to anyone?

Update: To experiment, please use the following instructions (Linux/Ubuntu, please modify as appropriate for other OS/environments):

```````
git clone https://github.com/besm6/dispak.git
sudo apt install automake
sudo apt install bison
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
export BESM6_PATH=$HOME/share/besm6
cat > test.b6 << EOF
USER 419900RC5^
LPR 128^
DISK 67(4002)^
EEB1A3
*NAME SCHEMA
*     Lines with 5 spaces after * are comments
*     E. g.  add 5 spaces after *  next line to see loader output
*NO LOAD LIST
*     The next line enables max heap size
*CALL YESMEMORY
*     The next 3 lines are akin to ld -u SCHEMA -l <library>; ./a.out
*MAIN SCHEMA
*PERSO:670702
*EXECUTE
*RED
*0STA*NN*RG*1RL*0MCS1 20
*3/
*MDLorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
*MDconsectetur adipiscing elit,
*MDsed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
*MDut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
*MD
*MD
*P
*E
*END
*END FILE
``````
EFINISH
EOF
```````

The lines between `*EXECUTE` and `*END FILE` are the standard input to the program being executed.
Then running `~/bin/dispak -l test.b6` should produce the sample output above. The `-l` option is needed to make sure that all Latin letters having identical Cyrillic analogs are output as Latin rather than Cyrillic.

Comment: There's a discussion here in Russian with some of those formatting strings: https://groups.google.com/g/besm6/c/gENjMf9N6zU/m/LWZ643wLY7MJ

Comment: @snips-n-snails That was me.

Comment: @snips-n-snails It's only relatively recently that I was able to find the actual tool to render those documents and to fix all the lurking emulator bugs which prevented it from running properly.

Comment: Is this related: https://spamsink.livejournal.com/655661.html ?

Comment: @UncleBod When I first discovered documents in that format, not being able to render them yet, I've asked some of my friends to ask around. Nothing came out of it then.

Comment: It seems that you have some access to the program, since you can experiment. Is it so?

Comment: @UncleBod I do. Without any control directives, it justifies, paginates and prints its input in two columns, with page numbers.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, since I think the topic is well suited for this site but the question could be improved a bit to ask something more specific. I don't think you'll be able to select the best (ie most accurate) answer to your question "does it ring a bell", so it'd be great to edit at least that part to ask either specific technical details or history of the product etc. as it is right now is opinion-based and thus against the guidelines

Comment: Do you have any links to where to find the tool you used to render the text?

Comment: @tuomas The intent of the question "Does it ring a bell?" is to elicit an answer with technical details and/or history of the product. It is not an opinion-based question, it's an idiom.

Comment: @UncleBod All the necessary bits and pieces -- i. e. the emulator and the disk images -- are on [GitHub](https://github.com/besm6/); I'll try and prepare detailed instructions.

Comment: It looks like a markup language or terminal control sequences.

Comment: @UncleBod Please see update.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Of course it looks like a markup language, it is read by a page layout program.

Comment: So, since (as I thought) this is a program that was run on the BESM-6, We know that that a probably time frame for the Schema markup language might have been up to 1990 (The computer was made up to 1987). Are there any file time stamps etc that can narrow down this a bit?

Comment: One more thing; since this is the related to the BESM-6: the program is apparently called schema on this computer.  If it did exist on another platform it might have used another name. It might even be a Soviet system of markup.

Comment: @UncleBod I remember seeing similarly rendered documents since early-to-mid 80s. Indeed, the Unified System for Programming Documentation -- [ЕСПД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Единая_система_программной_документации) --  has been adopted as a USSR standard in late 70s. As most computers in the USSR were of the cloned kind ([ES EVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ES_EVM), [SM EVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SM_EVM)), with ripped system software, a logical hypothesis is that the provenance of the documentation system is similar.

Comment: This reminds me of something I once saw that was used to print to a label or receipt printer. I will see if I can dig it up again.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's plausible, please do.